# how to execute Python 3.3 script in Spyder console with variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

how can I execute Python 3.3 script in Spyder console, and that has variables?

My sample code (C:/test/myfile.py) is

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

I have tried exec(open("C:\test\myfile.py").read()) - and the error I get is "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. I want to supply the variables first = "1st", second = "2nd", third = "3rd". How can I write the exec() so that it can handle the inputs?

I'm using Python 3.3, 64-bit installation, Windows OS, installation: WinPython.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python/89243#89243

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to go

`Run > Configuration per file`

(or hit `Ctrl+F6`) and in the dialog that it appears you need to check

`Command line options`

and write (for example) there

`1 2 3`

After closing this dialog and hitting `F5`, you'll see the output you are expecting.

*Note*: Please remember that these command line options are saved between Spyder restarts as part of the file run config, so if you want to change them, you need to hit `Ctrl+F6` again.

Comment: How can I use environment variables in the `Run->Configure->Command Line Options` ?  I tried something like `%myEnvironmentVar%\file.txt`, but Spyder appends the current working directory to it.

Comment: You can't pass a file environment variables in that dialog, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to save the config in the environment or anywhere else ? Each time I restart my machine I have to re-config...

Comment: Configurations per file are saved on disk, unless there's an issue while doing that (e.g. a permissions error on Spyder's config directory).

Answer (score 13):

What also works is the IPython console of Spyder is:

> In [1]: runfile('C:/yourfolder/myfile.py',args='one two three')