# how to put image files from one folder to make a video in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I have written a code to collect all image files from one folder, so that I can make a video out of it.

But while compiling I  getting an error saying `"Error creating movie, return code: 4 Try running with --verbose-debug"`

```
  #import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import glob, os
from PIL import Image
fig = plt.figure()
#size = 128, 128
ims=[]
#print(len(ims))
#im=Image.open(ims[5])
#im.show()
for infile in glob.glob("*.png"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im1=plt.imshow(im)
    ims.append([im1])
print(len(ims))    
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims)
ani.save('MovWave.mpeg', writer="ffmpeg")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with `--verbose-debug` ? Your code works for me, maybe there's a problem with `ffmpeg`

Comment: I donot know how does that work .

Comment: instead of running `python script.py` do `python script.py --verbose-debug` it will print more info on console

Comment: in windows and spyder compiler how and where ??

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502876/how-to-execute-python-3-3-script-in-spyder-console-with-variables

Comment: Couldn't do it .. Can you be please guide me further.